# basics needed for studying Laplace Transform

Tags: laplace-transform

Could anyone list out the basic concepts needed to study Laplace Transform or from where should I start.I was studying Z transform but I knew that Z transform is the finite version of Laplace Transform.

Also could you site any websites or references that would help in learning Laplace Transform.

Comment: Wikipedia is a good start.

Comment: Here's a good place to start (note that there are references at the end of the article):  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform

Comment: but while looking in wiki I can't understand anything.Could anyone explain Laplace transform in simple terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best video I have found for Laplace Transform was this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvbdoSeGAgI

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hqOboV2jgVo

MIT professor explains where it comes from, its analogue: Power Series and so on. It will take 13 minutes of your time but you will understand the concept completely!

Comment: could you please explain why power series converges for x<1.Is it do to sum of infinite terms in GP.

Comment: Yes if you look at power series, each successive term is multiplied by $x$. and hence if $|x|<1$ then the GP converges to sum to infinity formula.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to books you can visit [this site](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/LaplaceIntro.aspx) for a nice introduction. If you prefer videos you can always visit [this site](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-equations/laplace-transform) and watch the whole playlist. For a general overview read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) wikipedia article.